# Using OleDb.OleDb??? vb code ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview, oledb

I am trying to load my datagridview call dgvInfo with information for my database. I am quite new to vb and I don't understand where the problem lies in my code at the moment.

```
Private Sub frmProductInformation_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
    Dim readit As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=N:\data\GameHQ.accdb"
    conn.Open()
    readit = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    readit.Read()
    dt.Load(readit)
    dgvInfo.DataSource = dt
    dgvInfo.Refresh()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

This is my code and I hope someone is able to point out if I've missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to properly initialize your cmd. Assuming you don't use transactions, simply put your query and connection to your cmd. Btw - you didn't specify any SQL query yet:

```
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim readit As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=N:\data\GameHQ.accdb"
conn.Open()
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from <whatever you select from>", conn)
readit = cmd.ExecuteReader()
readit.Read()
dt.Load(readit)
dgvInfo.DataSource = dt
dgvInfo.Refresh()
conn.Close()
```